Pester 'It' or 'Context' array iteration
Pester 5.6.1
Powershell 7.4.5
Here's the deal.  I have data that I am loading in the BeforeDiscovery.  I can reference all the variables within at the Run stage...no problem there.  Even the string arrays.  What I cannot do...is loop over the string arrays.  It just completely ignores them:

The roles are definately there -> 
But it completely ignores the tests...it WILL break at tests that do not reference an array:


All variables used with -ForEach has to be available in Discovery-phase, not just the source $account. Use a BeforeDiscovery-block inside the Describe to make $roles available. E.g.
$c = New-PesterConfiguration
$c.Run.ScriptBlock = {
    BeforeDiscovery {
        $account = @{
            'name' = 'one'
            'roles' = @('web', 'db')
        }, @{
            'name'  = 'two'
            'roles' = @('app', 'file')
        }
    }
    Describe 'Account <name>' -ForEach $account {
        BeforeDiscovery {
            [string[]]$serverroles = $_.roles
        }
        Context 'Has role <_>' -ForEach $serverroles {
            It 'Test 1' {
                1 | Should -Be 1
            }
        }
    }
}
$c.Output.Verbosity = 'Detailed'
$c.Run.PassThru = $true
$r = Invoke-Pester -Configuration $c

# Output
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 4 tests in 26ms.
Running tests.
Describing Account one
 Context Has role web
   [+] Test 1 6ms (1ms|4ms)
 Context Has role db
   [+] Test 1 3ms (1ms|1ms)

Describing Account two
 Context Has role app
   [+] Test 1 3ms (1ms|2ms)
 Context Has role file
   [+] Test 1 2ms (1ms|1ms)
Tests completed in 153ms
Tests Passed: 4, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Inconclusive: 0, NotRun: 0


This was indeed my problem...nothing to do with the array..it works fine.  I THINK I get it now...in the discovery phase it needs to know what to supply during the run phase...hence why it just completely skipped it...
